# Problems with telegram pop-up notifications

Tags: python, telegram

I am experiencing some problems with notifocations from my telegram channels. I have running some 6 channels that recieve messages from different python scripts and different VM's.

For 4 of the channels I get a pop-up notification on my laptop and mobile phone but for 2 channels I don't get any pop-up notification.

I hope maybe 1 of you had the same experience / problem and know how to solve.

I checked the settings for notifications on all of my channels but I can't find any reason of the different behavior for each of the channels.

I also did some research on the internet but I can't find an solution yet.